# Compare multiple list boxes in multiple if statements

Tags: c#, button, textbox, listbox

The submit button here is supposed to check to see if the answer typed into a text box matches up with the correct answer in a list box, except there are for list boxes (2 for each 'subject'). How do I get it to work for both types of question without erroring out on the second type (in this case it errors for the second if statement)? The commented out part is a second way that I tried to do it.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lsbMathAns.SelectedItem.ToString() == txtAnswer.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Correct answer. Well Done!", "Great Job!");
    else if
        (lsbGeoAns.SelectedItem.ToString() == txtAnswer.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Correct answer. Well Done!", "Great Job!");


    //if (this.txtAnswer.Text.ToLower() == this.lsbGeoAns.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower())
    //    MessageBox.Show("Correct answer. Well Done!", "Great Job!");
    //else
    //    MessageBox.Show("Sorry. Try Again...", "Wrong Answer");
    //if (this.txtAnswer.Text == this.lsbMathAns.SelectedItem.ToString())
    //    MessageBox.Show("Correct answer. Well Done!", "Great Job!");
    //else
    //    MessageBox.Show("Sorry. Try Again...", "Wrong Answer");
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. If the user is supposed to be typing the answer to the first question in the `txtAnswer` box, why would it be permitted for them to provide the answer that goes with the `lsbGeoAns` list? You could accomplish that using `||` in a single `if`, but it doesn't seem like that's actually the right UI. You need to make sure you know which question the user's supposed to be answering, and compare the user's answer to the _single_ correct answer for that question. Beyond that, without a good [mcve] and a clearer question, I don't see how this can be answered.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is difficult to properly explain because of all the parts that go into it. There are two different types: geography and math and other buttons which aren't relevant right now. The questions are imported from text file into list boxes so to check each subject's response is correct, need to create an if, but errors out on second part even if using || when gets to second subject, just an error. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: _"Hope that helps a little"_ -- Nope. Doesn't help even a little bit. Please read [ask]. See also the articles linked at the bottom of that page. And read [mcve] again too. When you write your question, make a _real effort_ to put yourself in the place of the person who is reading it. They know nothing about your scenario. Given them all the information they need. Make sure you do not give them _any_ information that they don't need.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your manners certainly don't help **at all**. If you cannot help, just let us try our best here, OK?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can something like this solve your problem?

```
if (lsbMathAns.SelectedItem != null &&  lsbMathAns.SelectedItem.ToString() == txtAnswer.Text) ...
```

or

```
if (lsbMathAns.SelectedIndex >= 0 && lsbMathAns.SelectedItem.ToString() == txtAnswer.Text) ...
```

Comment: The first part of this when incorporated into an else if works perfectly. Thank you very much @GiorgosAltanis

Comment: But you have to put it in the "if" part as well.

Comment: Right, I mistyped the first time. I meant when I add an else if for the second 'subject' type it works perfectly. I did use the if first.

Comment: And of course you are welcome, and you are welcome to Stack Overflow as well. Don't let such attitudes discourage you.

Comment: And by the way @PeterDuniho it was indeed an answer to the question, since it solved the problem. Now would you be kind enough to undo your downvote (which I am sure is yours) and comment briefly?